# What is "l -adic sheaf"

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Recently, I am reading a paper about "algebraic trace functions". This paper gives a definition as follows:

Definition 2.1 (trace functions). Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an $\ell$-adic middle-extension sheaf pure of weight zero, which is lisse on an open set $U$. The trace function associated to $\mathcal{F}$ is defined by
$$K: x \in \mathbb{F}_p \rightarrow ι(\mathrm{tr}(\mathrm{Frob}_x | V_{\mathcal{F}})),$$
where Frobx denotes the geometric Frobenius at $x \in \mathbb{F}_p$, and $V_{\mathcal{F}}$ is a finite-dimensional $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{\ell}$-vector space, which is corresponding to a continuous finite-dimensional Galois representation and unramified at every closed point $x$ of $U$.

I have learned some basic knowledge about "sheaf", "local fields", and "algebraic geometry".

But I don't know how can I find the following conceptions:

1. l-adic sheaf,
2. the geometric Frobenius at $x\in \mathbb{F}_ p$ .

Comment: For 1, it depends on from where you're reading it, but it's probably about a particular technicality used to organize and talk about limits of torsion coefficients commonly used in étale cohomology, cf. Freitag-Kiehl Chap 1 § 12.

Comment: You're probably reading the Grothendieck's trace formula? In which case 2 would just be the Spec's of the ring Frobenii glued together. cf. Wikipedia

Comment: Thanks @Hypatia du Bois-Marie